# How to remotely send command to a robot connected to a separate machine through serial port?

Tags: serial

I work with a XL20 robotic tube sorter(lets say it's called X) which is connected to lets say computer(Y - IP: 10.216.1.222 - Running win7) through serial(com port 8 at 9600 baud and odd parity). If I open putty at computer Y and send my commands to the Xl 20, it works just fine.

Now I have a computer(Z- ip: 10.216.1.223 - Running win7) which is in the same network and I want to connect and send instruction to the Xl20 from this computer via putty or some other means.

Basically I'm trying to remotely communicate to the XL20 which is connected to a computer through serial port, so can anyone point me to any useful guide, documentation, clue or suggestion about how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a TCP server running on computer Y, which listens to any incoming TCP connections. After a TCP connection is established with computer Y it forwards incoming data to X and the responce form X gets forwarded to the incomind connection.

You can find hardware boxes that do this, like [this](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html). This yould replace PC Y.

A free software solution would be [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/combytcp/).

Comment: Perfect, to the point answer. Thank you 50k4.